# Android - ImageView won't show pic taken with camera

Tags: android, camera, imageview

Please bear with me... I've been looking around for **DAYS** for a working, bare-bones piece of code that starts the camera activity, takes a picture, and places it on a simple ImageView >.< The code posted below fires up the activity and takes the pic alright, but **the image does not show on the ImageView!** Just what is missing? :'(

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 0;

private static final int PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY = 1;

private Button mBtnCamera, mBtnGallery, mBtnCancel;

private ImageView mImageView;

private Uri mURI;
private String mPhotoPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgDisplayImage);

    mBtnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoCamera);
    mBtnGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoGallery);
    mBtnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

    mBtnCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent camera = new Intent();

            camera.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            camera.putExtra("crop", "true");

            File f = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            mURI = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "myFile.jpg"));

            camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mURI);

            startActivityForResult(camera, PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}   

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE)
    {
        // Result includes a Bitmap thumbnail?
        if (data != null)
        {
            if (data.hasExtra("data"))
            {
                //Bitmap thumbnail = data.getParcelableExtra("data");

                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                mImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
        }
        // If there is no thumbnail data, the image will have been stored in target output URI.
        else
        {

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]
                            {
                                Media.DATA, 
                                Media.DATE_ADDED, 
                                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION
                            }, 
                            Media.DATE_ADDED, 
                            null, 
                            "date_added ASC"
            );

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    mURI = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.DATA)));
                    mPhotoPath = mURI.toString();
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();
            }

            // Resize full image to fit out in image view.
            int width = mImageView.getWidth();
            int height = mImageView.getHeight();

            BitmapFactory.Options factoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            factoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(/*mURI.getPath()*/ mPhotoPath, factoryOptions);

            int imageWidth = factoryOptions.outWidth;
            int imageHeight = factoryOptions.outHeight;

            // Determine how much to scale down the image
            int scaleFactor = Math.min(
                    imageWidth/width,
                    imageHeight/height
                    );

            // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill view

            factoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            factoryOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
            factoryOptions.inPurgeable = true;

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(/*mURI.getPath()*/ mPhotoPath, factoryOptions);

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try giving  Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  in the if condition instead of  Bitmap thumbnail = data.getParcelableExtra("data");

Comment: Tried that, not working :( I added up your suggestion anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had same problem in some devices of samsung android Then I implemented logic to get path of captured photo.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE)
    {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Media.DATA, Media.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added ASC");
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.DATA)));
                photoPath = uri.toString();
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        }

        if(photoPath != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
            ///Do Implement your logic whatever you want.
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working, even after incorporating your suggestions :(

I'll edit the main thread to show how the whole code looks now, too long to paste everything here.

Comment: Also, I'm not testing this on a VM but on a Galaxy S3 phone.

Comment: I had same problem in samsung. Please post my code in onActivityResult and then you will get the path of bitmap.

Comment: I just did. Maybe I again managed to screw up somewhere. Care to take another look? :)

Comment: @Emiliano De Santis  Take look at my answer and let me know if any problem you will have but implement carefully.

Comment: Found it. After DAYS UPON DAYS, seems this is it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Its pleasure to me I helped you. Same problem I had earlier then implemented this logic.

Answer (score 1):

Tried and tested to work on a Galaxy S3 phone. Credit to TGMCians for his help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 0;

private static final int PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY = 1;

private Button mBtnCamera, mBtnGallery, mBtnCancel;

private ImageView mImageView;

private Uri mURI;
private String mPhotoPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgDisplayImage);

    mBtnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoCamera);
    mBtnGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoGallery);
    mBtnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

    mBtnCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent camera = new Intent();

            camera.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            camera.putExtra("crop", "true");

            File f = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            mURI = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "myFile.jpg"));

            camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mURI);

            startActivityForResult(camera, PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}   

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE)
        {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]
                            {
                                Media.DATA, 
                                Media.DATE_ADDED, 
                                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION
                            }, 
                            Media.DATE_ADDED, 
                            null, 
                            "date_added ASC"
            );

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    mURI = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.DATA)));
                    mPhotoPath = mURI.toString();
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();
            }
            if (data != null)
            {
                if (data.hasExtra("data"))
                {
                    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Intent bundle does not have the 'data' Extra");

                    int width = mImageView.getWidth();
                    int height = mImageView.getHeight();

                    BitmapFactory.Options factoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    factoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(/*mURI.getPath()*/ mPhotoPath, factoryOptions);

                    int imageWidth = factoryOptions.outWidth;
                    int imageHeight = factoryOptions.outHeight;

                    // Determine how much to scale down the image
                    int scaleFactor = Math.min(
                            imageWidth/width,
                            imageHeight/height
                            );

                    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill view

                    factoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    factoryOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
                    factoryOptions.inPurgeable = true;

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(/*mURI.getPath()*/ mPhotoPath, factoryOptions);

                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Picture taking activity NOT returning RESULT_OK");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

(and a slight delay) right inside the

```
 if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE)
```

block. I think the problem might be that your device isn't refreshing the Media store correctly.

(of course the better action would be to use MediaScanner to [scan your file](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29))